# DotNetCore 3.1 WPF grid layout manager issue

Tags: wpf, .net-core, layout, grid

i have a slight problem with the grid layout manager in WPF, using DotNetCore 3.1. I have the following code:

```
        <TabControl Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
            <TabItem Header="APM ops">
                <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <GroupBox Name="CheckStatus" Header="Check status" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="0" Rows="1" Columns="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">HAC processes</Button>
                            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">Nanny processes</Button>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Name="RestartProcesses" Header="Restart services" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <CheckBox>hornetq</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>marble_supervisor</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>odb</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>offline_engine</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>mercuryAS</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>businessImpactService</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>pmanager</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>db_loader</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>marble_loader</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>schedulergw</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>marble_worker</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>wde</CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox>marble_matcher</CheckBox>
                            <RadioButton>(make a selection)</RadioButton>
                            <Button>Restart</Button>
                            <RadioButton>(make a selection)</RadioButton>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </GroupBox>
                </UniformGrid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Java VM ops"/>
            <TabItem Header="Server cfg"/>
            <TabItem Header="Credential cfg"/>
        </TabControl>
```

what I get is this:

[image]

What I would like to get is something more like this, where the gap betwenn the two GroupBoxes is minimized and there is some sort of margin between the checkboxes of the second Groupbox:

[image]

However, I don't seem to be able to find the correct controls and/or properties. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to use the Grid property, not the UniformGrid ("duh!")... I guess in retrospect, it was kind of obvious, but I apparently couldn't see the forest for the trees.